# Coldfusion 11 version not updating after hotfix installed

Tags: coldfusion

After installing Hotfix 11 on Coldfusion 11 my version number is stuck at 11,0,03,301867.  It shows the update level correctly at chf11000011.jar.

The Server works, however it shows 8 updates are not installed (it was fewer before the update).

Comment: How did you install the update?

Comment: Via java -jar hotfix_011.jar